# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined, XAMPP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql

This is the PHP file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "palestra";

try{
    $Nome = $_POST["Nome"];
    $Cognome = $_POST["Cognome"];
    $Email = $_POST["Email"];
    $Password = $_POST["Password"];
    $Sesso = $_POST["Sesso"];
    $Città = $_POST["Città"];
    $Corso = $_POST["Corso"];

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `palestra`.`clienti` (`Nome`, `Cognome`, `Email`, `Password`, `Sesso`, `Città`, `Corso`) VALUES (:Nome, :Cognome, :Email, :Password, :Sesso, :Città, :Corso)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':Nome', $Nome);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Cognome', $Cognome);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Email', $Email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Password', $Password);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Sesso', $Sesso);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Città', $Città);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Corso', $Corso);

    $stmt->execute();
    
    echo "Registrazione avvenuta con successo";
}catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed"  . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE `clienti` (
  `Nome` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Cognome` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Sesso` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `Città` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Corso` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

When i click the "register" button on the HTML file the registration fails with that error code, why?
I'm using Xampp and MySql to do that exercise for school.

Comment: Please ALWAYS shoa us all the error message and not a summary

Comment: PLease dont store Plain Text Passwords. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is the full error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: @RiggsFollyThe safety for now is not a problem, it's a simple exercise for school

Comment: I fixed, accent are always a problem, my bad...